# Trouble setting chmod in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I am creating a theme for my blog and I need to set the `customcss.css` to writable `777` so that when I change the design in the backend it writes to this file.

Everything works 100% when I set the `chmod` to `777` manually, but when I try to set the chmod to `777` when activating it display this error message:

> Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/wptest/wp-content/themes/ctheme/ThemeFunctions/th‌​emeinstall.php on line 74

The code I am using is as follows:

```
$rootpage = get_theme_root();
chmod($rootpage . '/ctheme/css/customcss.css', 0777);
```

I have searched this website and unfortunately found nothing similar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a good description. You should say what the actual outcome is. Also enable WP_DEBUG, this might reveal more error information to you.

Comment: @hakre i apologies for that, sorry... here is the error messages i am getting Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/wptest/wp-content/themes/ctheme/ThemeFunctions/themeinstall.php on line 74 - That is the only error message i am getting

Comment: Just a standard permission denied. The user executing that command is not able to change permissions. Change the owner of the directory and this might be possible. However, keep it with manual chmodding. Also a theme should never need to chmod the directory to 777 IMHO.

Comment: @hakre - The reason i am doing this is because in order to write to the css file, it needs to have writing permission and without setting it to 777 it will not write. How else would you do this?

Comment: chmod manually. otherwise shell_exec with sudo the chmod operation in shell. And take a bit more care: Only you want something must not mean you *can* do it - especially as you are having a problem with permissions. You are denied to do that. I hope it's more clear for you now.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the command manually, you are a user in the shell *that is allowed* to change the mode.

When you write the php function `chmod` into the script, it will be executed by another user, the user that is executing PHP.

Because that user is *not allowed* to change the mode of the file. That is why you see the error.

Unless you do not change the user that is executing PHP (to change the user that is then finally changing the mode), this error will not go away.

Comment: The fix here would be to chown the file to apache (or whatever user is running the script). If the back-end is creating files, then he should chown them to the appropriate user as well.